# PHMagick not working after code moved to a different server

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I built a pdf generator script for one of my clients and everything works properly. He then decided that he wanted me to create a thumbnail image from the PDF to display on another page, so I came across PHMagick and that seemed to do the trick.

The following code **worked** on my building server (iPage -- I think it's debian?), but now that I've moved it to his VPS, it is no longer working. **FPDF has no trouble generating the pdf, so it is not a permissions issue.**

Code:

```
require("phmagick/phmagick.php");
$pdf->Output("pdf.pdf");

$p = new phmagick('','pdf.png');
$p->debug = true;
$p->resize(800);

$p->acquireFrame("pdf.pdf");
```

This code returns the following error:

> Error executing "convert "pdf.pdf"[0] "pdf.png"" 
> return code: 127 
> command output :"sh: convert: command not found"

I have not changed any of the code since I moved it from the original server, and I just **copied the entire site** over, so why is PHMagick not working now? How do I get it to recognize convert.php in the plugins folder?

*Just a note:* I am only using PHMagick, not the whole of ImageMagick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHMagic appears to be using the command line `convert` command in background.

Most likely that command is simply not installed on the server.

Comment: How do I install it then? All I had to do on my iPage server was just require the phmagick.php file and everything worked instantly.

Comment: Maybe the imagemagick package was already installed on your system? Anyway: first test _if_ it is installed or not (on the command line). If not you have to install it, look for the imagemagick package. That is what provides the `convert` command. Note: since you installed just a php file but not a software package using the software management system no dependencies are resolved for you.

Comment: Is there a way to run the convert command through PHP rather than command line?

Comment: @David: Sorry, maybe I don't understand that question. Aparently the answer is yes, since that is exactly what your PHMagick solution does on background. You can do that yourself writing a small script executing a `system()` or `exec()` and running `convert` that way.

Answer (score 2):

PHMagic use the command line `convert`,`composite` etc... commands in background.
These commands are only available if ImageMagick is installed in your server.

In your previous server ImageMagick must have been installed.

**Ipage** sometimes do not pre install ImageMagick on their **VPS** servers. And you might not be able to install it your self ( through terminal login using ... `yum install ImageMagick` ) coz you will be prompt for root password.

To make sure the ImageMagick binaries are installed in ur server, in ur case the `convert` command,
type this command in the ssh terminal...

`whereis convert`

If the path to the convert command is not shown, it means you need to install ImageMagick.

You will have to open a support ticket and ask them to install it for you

Answer (score 1):

As arkascha said, you'll need to install imagemagick. Try `yum install imagemagick` since you're running CentOS.

EDIT: May be a different capitalization: ImageMagick